# Python: Couldn't convert from String to Float

Tags: python, scikit-learn, sentiment-analysis

I followed this tutorial to implement sentiment analysis:
https://stackabuse.com/python-for-nlp-sentiment-analysis-with-scikit-learn/

but I'm not a pro so I don'T understand every step in detail.
Now, I wanted to apply it to new data, using this tutorial:
https://stackabuse.com/scikit-learn-save-and-restore-models/

but at the point

```
  score = pickle_model.score(Xtest, Ytest)
```

I get the Value error: could not convert from String to float 'positive' (Positive being a label for the sentiment analysis done earlier). What surprises me is that the error happens even when using X_train and y_train (from the first tutorial), but

```
text_classifier.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

works just fine without any errors. So I am assuming that the fit() method does something that the score() method does not, and this creates the problem. However, I have no idea how to fix it.

Here is the full error message:

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)

```
<ipython-input-210-070f6faef44c> in <module>
     34 print(len(X_train))
     35 print(len(y_train))
---> 36 score = pickle_model.score(X_train, y_train)
     37 print("Test score: {0:.2f} %".format(100 * score))
     38 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\base.py in score(self, X, y, sample_weight)
    408         y_pred = self.predict(X)
    409         # XXX: Remove the check in 0.23
--> 410         y_type, _, _, _ = _check_reg_targets(y, y_pred, None)
    411         if y_type == 'continuous-multioutput':
    412             warnings.warn("The default value of multioutput (not exposed in "

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\metrics\regression.py in _check_reg_targets(y_true, y_pred, multioutput)
     76     """
     77     check_consistent_length(y_true, y_pred)
---> 78     y_true = check_array(y_true, ensure_2d=False)
     79     y_pred = check_array(y_pred, ensure_2d=False)
     80 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py in check_array(array, accept_sparse, accept_large_sparse, dtype, order, copy, force_all_finite, ensure_2d, allow_nd, ensure_min_samples, ensure_min_features, warn_on_dtype, estimator)
    494             try:
    495                 warnings.simplefilter('error', ComplexWarning)
--> 496                 array = np.asarray(array, dtype=dtype, order=order)
    497             except ComplexWarning:
    498                 raise ValueError("Complex data not supported\n"

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\numeric.py in asarray(a, dtype, order)
    536 
    537     """
--> 538     return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order)
    539 
    540
```

ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'positive'

and here'S the piece of code the error occurs in:

```
vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer (max_features=2500, min_df=1, max_df=1, stop_words=stopwords.words('english'))
chat_data = vectorizer.fit_transform(chat_data).toarray()

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(chat_data, chat_labels, test_size=0.2, random_state=0)

text_classifier = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=200, random_state=0)
text_classifier.fit(X_train, y_train)
predictions = text_classifier.predict(X_test)
X_train = np.array(X_train).reshape((-1,1))
y_train = np.array(y_train).reshape((-1,1))
print(len(X_train))
print(len(y_train))
score = pickle_model.score(X_train, y_train)
print("Test score: {0:.2f} %".format(100 * score))
```

Comment: Why you assume the `X_train, y_train` that passed to `fit()` are not numeric?

Comment: Where does the error occur? That isn’t the full error message, isn’t it?

Comment: @DavidS: what do you mean? I only assume that fit does sth different or expectes different kinds of parameters since it does not throw the error, when it's the same data.

Comment: @AMC I edited the OP, hope that helps!

Comment: @ApeLincoln should `score = pickle_model.score(X_train, y_train)` be `score = text_classifier.score(X_train, y_train)`?
You didn't explain where the model `pickle_model` came from.
It looks like your y_train labels should be `0` or `1` not strings. You could try converting with something like:
```
y_train_converted = np.where(y_train=='positive', 1, 0)
```

Comment: @RobertKing the pickle_model was from the other tutorial. Also, thanks I got it to work with converting, however I would need 1 for positive 0 for neutral and -1 for negative or sth like that. Also, with your solution I got a score of -885%, but I have no idea what it means :D ... I just assume it's pretty bad

Comment: Also, when I make the change you suggested regarding the text_classifier, I get the following error: TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'

Comment: Sounds like maybe you have some unexpected values in your `y_train` vector. Maybe try something like `set(y_train)` to see what the unique values are.

Comment: I get an unhashable type error. Also, this is the thing, I don't know what the hell happens when x_train, x_test, etc are created. Both chat_data and chat_labels have a length of 250, but when i print out len(y_train) i get 42586 ? How is this possible?